# Unit test whether a function object gets called

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Mocks are used to detect function calls. What can be done if we have a class with a function object:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        A(){};
        void doit(){
            //...
            if(f)
                f();
            //...
        }
        function<void()> f;
};

int main(){
    A a;
    a.f = [] () { cout << "hello\n"; };
    a.doit();
}
```

Is there a way to test wheter `f` was called in function `doit()`?

Comment: you could add a variable which changes when it was called. and then check if it has the changed value.

Comment: With Mock, you have `EXPECT_CALL`

Answer (score 1):

I needed just that a few days ago. What I ended up doing was something like this:

```
class TestHelper
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD0(foo, void());
};
```

And than, when i instantiate my object, i pass the mocked function or a lambda that use that function to be more exact (you could also use std::bind).

Note: To you also need to declare that you want to test that function call. For that you have `EXPECT_CALL`.

In your example it would look like this:

```
TEST(My_test)
{
    A a;
    TestUtil helper;
    EXPECT_CALL(helper, foo()).Times(1); // Or whatever other matcher and action you want to test.
    a.f = [] () { helper.foo(); };
    a.doit();
}
```

> Note that you will need google-mock for doing this.

Comment: Just `using FMock = testing::MockFunction<void()>;` instead of `TestHelper`; see https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#mock-classes